# How to call a function-like class (a class whose constructor does all the work)

Tags: c++

> I'm asking this just to know - not necessarily my code will end up using this strategy.

Suppose I have a class similar to this:

```
class Calc
{
public:
    Calc( int &X, int &Y, CalcType aType )
    {
        int h = Helper( X );
        // All the hard work will be done here.  
    }

    int Helper( int I ) { // Do something }

    enum CalcType
    {
        Add,
        Sub,
        Mul,
        Div
    };
};
```

Will optimisation remove this call:

```
Calc( X, Y, Calc::Add );
```

Will it remove this:

```
Calc iCalc( X, Y, Calc::Add ); // iCalc will be unused hence after.
```

Any reasons not to do something like this (where the work is done in the constructor)?

Comment: Are you asking if you can call a method directly, without having to instantiate a class?

Comment: No. `Calc( X, Y, Calc::Add )` is the instantiation of the class.

Comment: What's the purpose of constructing an object then? Just use a regular non member function.

Comment: I completely understand - I'm considering just using a function instead. But the enum is associated with the operation the class performs, so the class also act as a namespace.

Comment: The other thing is that there is some possibility that subclasses will be used to extend the functionality of the base class.

Comment: You can acheive this by explicitly calling the original function from the new function that extends it. And use a namespace if all you need is a namespace.

Comment: And what exactly would I gain by doing this? Instead of calling `class` I call `namespace::function` - so more to type.

Comment: More to type? `Calc iCalc` vs. `Calc::iCalc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is no, just because object isn't used doesn't mean the instantiation will be optimized out.

If the constructor is empty and the object is never used or only created as a temporary, it is possible for a smart compiler to optimize it away. In your case since " // All the hard work will be done here. " this is not the case.

Comment: I'm not positive what's being asked, but I **think** you've answered it.  In short, an optimizer is not supposed to change functionality.

Comment: note that in the class definition, everything is private. But let's suppose that only the constructor is accessible, wouldn't it make sense to have the compiler optimize away the object instantiation, since the object is unusable anyway?

Comment: @DrewDormann: What is being asked is if the first two calls will be optimised away, and if there is anything substantially flawed with the class in question that I may not be aware of (as it looks weird to me to do things this way as much as it does to others). So I guess it has been answered.